# How does `ungetch` work?

Tags: c

I searched everywhere, but I cannot find the answer to this!  I'm working on the exercise from the K&R C books with a function they call `getop`.  When it peeks at the next character from the input and sees that it isn't a digit, where does the character get stored when `unget` is called?  I can compile and run the code so I know it works, I just want to know where the character has been stored.

```
int getop(char s[])
{
    int i, c;

    while ((s[0] = c = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t')
        ;
    s[1] = '\0';
    if (!isdigit(c) && c != '.')
        return c; /* not a number */
    i = 0;
    if (isdigit(c)) /*collect integer part*/
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
            ;
    if (c == '.') /*collect fraction part*/
        while (isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
            ;
    s[i] = '\0';
    if (c != EOF)
        ungetch(c);
    return NUMBER;
}
```

Comment: Some man edit my text and change essence.

Comment: I tried to read your original question. It makes absolutely no sence. Can you get someone around you to help you with your English so that your question understandable?

Comment: I will found , so until that,i simply asked when i input for example "123" and press enter getchar read 123 and '\n', and where '\n' goin, when i saw that not goin in buffer?

Comment: Note that `ungetch(EOF)` is a no-op, so you don't need the `if (c != EOF)` conditional.

Comment: Thanks for recorrecting my question.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really peek, it reads the char into the stream's buffer. On an unbuffered stream, or when you've read nothing after opening the file or seeking, `ungetc()` isn't guaranteed to work.

Comment: This is slightly incorrect. `ungetc` is always guaranteed to work at least once, regardless of whether the stream is buffered.

Comment: @R.. Then I found my second error in "C: A Reference Manual": "One character of pushback is guaranteed provided the stream is buffered and..."

Comment: I wouldn't bother using any reference for standard C functions except the C standard itself. Most of them are full of errors like this... :(